# delete row in UITableView objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with 7 section and in each section 2 rows, I don't know why my delete button doesn't  work!! and not appear in cells

would you please help me!
Thanks in advance!

[image]

day.m

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arry addObject:@"test"];
    [arry addObject:@"hey"];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}

-(void)addNewItem
{
    [arry addObject:@"New Day"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

// ... standard methods to override

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 7;
    //_week.days.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arry count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return @"Monday";
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return @"Tuesday";
    }
    else if(section == 2)
    {
        return @"Wednesday";
    }
    else if(section == 3)
    {
        return @"Thuesday";
    }
    else if(section == 4)
    {
        return @"Friday";
    }
    else if(section == 5)
    {
        return @"Saturday";
    }
    else
    {
        return @"Sunday";
    }
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // [self.monthTitle removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [arry removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {   
    }   
}
```

**Edit1: after removing multiple selection from storyboard  delete button appears but when I click on delete button it's terminated**

[image]

Comment: but when I click on delete button it's terminated.. Means ??

Answer (score 1):

You didn't begin your table updates.
When you use the method "deleteRowsAtIndexPath", you must insert it between this methods:

```
// Begin update
[tableView beginUpdates];

// Perform update
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

// End update
[tableView endUpdates]
```

Comment: Not true, you only need to do that if you want to group multiple edits.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like you've set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES` (perhaps in your nib file, as I can't see that in the code). When that's the case, `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` will never be called, because the checkmarks only indicate the user's *selection*, not that these rows should be deleted.

You need a delete button of your own that is activated when you enter editing mode, similar to how you see it in the Mail app.

Comment: that's right right know I have delete button but when I use it my proces terminated

Comment: The problem is that you use the same array for all sections.

Answer (score 0):

you should first remove row from the datasource like this,

```
            [self.table_favpropertylist_array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPathRow];
            [tbl_FavDetails beginUpdates];

            UITableViewCell *cell=[tbl_FavDetails cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathRow inSection:0]];

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tbl_FavDetails indexPathForCell:cell];
            [tbl_FavDetails deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tbl_FavDetails endUpdates];
```

where self.table_favpropertylist_array is datasource ,tbl_FavDetails is tableview and indexPathRow is index at which row delete  button is clicked,

Thanks.